# Is pthread_mutex_destroy(p) mandatory right before free(p)?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Imagine I've got a pthread mutex somewhere on the heap.

```c
pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
```

Should I always destroy like this before freeing the memory?

```c
pthread_mutex_destroy(mutex);
free(mutex);
```

Or should I simply invoke `free()` without concerning myself with the destroy? From its man page it looks like it switches the mutex internal state back to *uninitialized*, so is it really necessary when I'm going to free the memory anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The thing about `pthread_mutex_destroy()` is that it returns an error code, which is very useful to confirm the state of the mutex in question. According to the man page:

> The pthread_mutex_destroy() function may fail if:
>
> EBUSY
> The implementation has detected an attempt to destroy the object referenced by mutex while it is locked or referenced (for example,
> while being used in a pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait())
> by another thread.
>
> EINVAL
> The value specified by mutex is invalid.

So, if you are already absolutely *certain* that the mutex is suitable for release, then you can just call `free(mutex)`. If you are just *assuming* that it is suitable, then strangeness is likely to ensue.

Comment: *then you can just call free(mutex)*  No, you can't - failing to call `pthread_mutex_destroy()` means resources may be leaked.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300838/4756299) on the question this has been marked a dupe of.

Comment: Thanks for the extra concurrency concerns about being able or not to destroy/deallocate it, but @AndrewHenle is right: on that other anser it is demonstrated that memory leaks might actually occurr when not invoking `pthread_mutex_destroy()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Good point. It certainly reinforces the requirement of absolute certainty about the state of the mutex in question.

Comment: `EBUSY` is implementation specific. Not all linux distributions appear to support it. In example, this is taken from the CentOS man pages: _"It shall be safe to destroy an initialized mutex that is unlocked.   Attempting  to destroy a locked mutex results in undefined behavior."_

Comment: @RiccardoT.: Yes, and according to The Open Group POSIX [specs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html#), the `pthread_mutex_destroy()` function returns an error code on failure, but _does not_ specifiy any error codes. So one should _definitely_ check the references for the specific implementation.